# More efficient for an Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have an assignment, in which we have to create a directory which stores names and an extension number. In the first part we have to store the information in just an Array. We have to be able to add an entry to the Array and also initially read a .txt file and store it in the Array. Finally it has to print the Array. I was just wondering what would be more efficient because I only started learning code the last few months and this is difficult for me.

1) Would it be better to first create an Array of size [9999] (because that is the max number of entries the directory could have because everyone has a unique four digit number). I have an INT called count which keeps a count of what the last Array[x] to be added so when I call a method like addEntry, it will add the Entry to [X+1].

The problems with this be is that from what I have read, Arrays are huge and it could have performance problems. Also I have to be able to make a 'lookup' method which should be able to search the Array for someones number by entering their name.

My other option:
2) When the file is read, it counts how many lines the file has (each entry will be on its own line) then creates an Array of the number of lines in the text file. Whenever I want to add a new Entry, I copy the Array into an ArrayList, then back to an Array with the new Entry added. However I also read that copying arrays is not so good too and in a realistic view, if someone was to use this directory they could be adding entries every day.

Aslong as I store in an Array and print the Array into a table it is all good, but what would be the best way to make the actual Array when you don't know the size? (Yes I know I can use ArrayList but its specifically said not to)

Also how would you go about deleting an Entry in the Array, if I use my way there would be a missing entry at Array[x] where x got deleted.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: I am not very clear about the question. You have a file like 3578.txt, you want to save 3578 in an array, and how many lines in 3578.txt?

Comment: Does it have to be an array?  A [`Map<Short, String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) ([`HashMap<Short, String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) most likely) would be a better storage type for this. (You may have to reverse the types mentioned above depending on which data is used for lookups.)

Comment: Use HashMap<Name,Number>

Comment: the file will be like Name<TAB>LastName<TAB>Number  and would be on its own line.

Comment: Has to be an Array for this part, the second part we have to do it again but with a map. But our teacher wants us to use an Array, if we dont do an Array we wont get ANY marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to initialize an array to the size that you **initially** need it. When you need to add items to the array after that, you can uses a memory copy rather than an object clone.

```
int[] arrayOne = new int[20];
int[] arrayTwo = new int[40];

System.arraycopy(arrayOne, 0, arrayTwo, 0, arrayOne.length);
```

This copy is actually very fast because it just makes a direct copy from memory. This is actually what the underlying code of array list does when it doubles in size.
If you want a "dynamic" sized array, you could write your own version of array list. 
For example:

- Starts at size 1
- Doubles in size when it gets full
- shifts objects on a delete using `System.arraycopy()`
- reduces in half when a delete causes size to be less than n/3